# Using GoDaddy domain with No-Ip

Tags: dns, hosting

I have a GoDaddy domain www.exmaple.com which points to 255.255.255.255 (fake IP of course). My web server is behind a router that forwards port 80 to the appropriate port. All fine and dandy. However, like 99% of people out there, I have a dynamic IP. So I set up a hostname with noip.com called helloworld.ddns.net, set up their update client on my server (so it can update them whenever the IP changes (hasn't happened yet but i'm hoping it works as advertised), and then went to godaddy.com to change my records. Which is where stuff gets as hairy as harambe.

I started off by removing my A record, and changing my CNAME to point to helloworld.ddns.net.

Didn't work.

Googled around, and found that I need/should use the noip NSs. So I went back to godaddy, and changed my nameservers from theirs to the noip ones... ns[1,2,3,4,5].no-ip.com.

Still doesn't work. Should also point out, that after I made this change I lost the ability to set any records on my domain name. Which I guess makes sense since there's no point in godaddy having a record if I'm not using their NSs.

Tl;dr: How do I point godaddy domain, www.example.com, to a noip hostname, helloworld.ddns.net, which in turn points to my dynamic home ip, x.x.x.x.

Comment: Thanks to the ape that downvoted without giving a reason.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally managed to solve my own issue, and I feel very silly for not realizing what the issue was before. The problem was that the CNAME was pointing to a subdomain (www) and therefore one couldn't access the site without including this in the URL. Summarised solution:

- GoDaddy now has CNAME with a specific host name (ex www) and the noip domain as the value
- No A record
- Kept the default GoDaddy NSs
- Configured forwarding w/o masking, to www.example.com... therefore, when someone tries to access example.com, they are automatically forwarded to the www subdomain.

A little bit of patience for propagation and everything was up and running.

Comment: what do you mean by "specific host name"?

Comment: When I deleted GoDaddy's A record it was replaced with a new A record which I cannot edit. How do you have No A record?

Comment: I can confirm this worked for me. However it does not seem to support adding things like SSL certs. Ideally I want to point my go daddy domain name at something that redirects it to my home IP. But also add a free letsencrypt SSL cert onto the godaddy domain.